# Using EF stores in an ASP.NET project without EF Core reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, separation-of-concerns

The recommended way to use default ASP.NET Identity with EF Core involves putting the following in the `ConfigureServices` method of your ASP.NET application's `Startup` class:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

This requires 2 things that don't seem like they belong in the ASP.NET Web project (a presentation-layer project): a reference to EF Core (to get the `AddEntityFrameworkStores` extension method), and a reference to `ApplicationDbContext` (which I'd have thought should be internal to the data access code in a persistence layer).

How can I avoid these references and separate concerns properly while still using this configuration for my site's identity?

Comment: Note that in .NET Core, references are transitive anyway. So even if ProjA references ProjB and ProjB references ProjC, ProjA still gets all references from ProjC. Having said that, you can delegate the config of this to your data project in the same way the `AddDbContext` extension method works in your code.

Comment: @DavidG I didn't know that.  So is there no way in .NET Core to properly separate concerns using an N-tier architecture?

Comment: Well you can, you just need to be a little more careful.

Comment: How, though?  Web references BLL, and BLL references DAL.  How can you avoid that?

Comment: Don't use code that directly relies on objects in projects you don't want to reference. You can use diagramming tools to help too.

Comment: I thought the whole point of selectively referencing stuff was to make it *impossible* to reference things that shouldn't be, and this is being touted as a feature not a bug?

Comment: Still, it seems crazy that that isn't the default.  Every time I add a reference, I have to go and change the csproj to add `PrivateAssets="All"` in.

Comment: @DavidG Could you please provide an answer to this question and give an example of delegating the config in the data project?

Comment: `PrivateAssets` will not help you here. That will pretty much only control what gets published with your project. But when you have a transitive dependemcy like `Web -> BLL -> DAL`, then the web project will *absolutely require* to have access to the DAL at run time. That’s how .NET works. It’s nothing new with Core.

Comment: @poke Yeah but I'm talking about design time.  I don't want my controller code to be able to access `DbContext`.

Comment: Well what you shouldn't really want is your repository code to be able to access an application service or web controller.

Comment: @PabloRecalde But if you implement a repository pattern to separate your specific DB access implementation from the presentation layer, wouldn't you want to prevent the presentation layer from side-stepping that and going straight to the DB access?

Comment: You have to respect your own constraints, even if some of them are not being enforced by the compiler. As already said, trasient dependencies make the outtermost project capable of accessing everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's worth noting that in .NET Core, references are transitive. This means that if `WebProj` references `BLLProj` and `BLLProj` references `DALProj`:

```
WebProj -> BLLProj -> DALProj
```

then `WebProj` still gets all the references from `DALProj`.

Having said that, you can delegate the config of this to your data project in the same way the `AddDbContext` extension method works in your code. This means the web project won't have any direct reference to any DAL objects.

For example, either in your BLL layer or even a completely separate project, you could have an extension method that will add your services to the DI container, something like this for example:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddDataAndIdentity(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    }
}
```

And in your web project, call it in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddDataAndIdentity(Configuration);
```

Additionally, there are tools that help you to visualise project dependencies. If you have Visual Studio Enterprise edition, you can [create a code map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/map-dependencies-across-your-solutions?view=vs-2019). Other tools such as [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper) can also help.